# How do I increase concurrent requests in Digital Ocean Droplet?

Tags: linux, apache, concurrency, varnish, digital-ocean

I have optimized a Digital Ocean Droplet (Ubuntu 12.04) using Varnish in front of Apache to serve thousands of web requests per second. When I ssh into my droplet and run

```
ab -n 100 -c 100 FULL_URL
```

I get 2000-3000 requests per second even when I raise the value. Varnish is working great.

However, when I run the same ApacheBench command from my local computer, I get all kinds of timeouts whenever concurrency goes above 20 or 30.

Why can my site handle hundreds of concurrent requests locally but only 20 or 30 through the Internet?

I have followed the guidelines of this blog: http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/ thinking that the problem is with the OS tcpip settings, but after a droplet reboot, there is no change.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The obvious answer is net congestion, what in the bandwidth and roundtrip values from your computer to the droplet?

Comment: Help me answer your question. Do you mean running a tracert? I'm assuming the problem is on Digital Ocean's end or on my server configuration. It appears as if after a flood of requests they lock out an IP address for a minute or two, but I am looking for confirmation and to see if anyone here might know about such a practice.

Comment: I mean usisng ping to determine roundtrip values, but if you're on doubt you can use ssh to create a TCP tunnel to your machine for the tests in order to avoid Digital Ocean's perimetral defenses

Comment: What is the specs on your own connection, what happens when you try to make 100 concurrent requests to any other host? You need a very good connection to run apache benchmark externally with results that are meaningful (which mostly means you need another good server connection).